# Is there a way to merge similar lines using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have two csv files. One is

```
    id_number,location_code,category,animal,quantity 
    12212,3,4,cat,2
    29889,7,6,dog,2
    98900,
    33221,1,8,squirrel,1
```

the second one is:

```
98900,2,1,gerbil,1
```

The second file may have a newline or something at the end (maybe or maybe not, I haven't checked), but only the one line of content. There may be three or four or more different varieties of the "second" file, but each one will have a first element (98900 in this example) that corresponds to an incomplete line in the first file similar to what is in this example.

Is there a way using powershell to automatically merge the line in the second (plus any additional similar) csv file into the matching line(s) of the first file, so that the resulting file is:

```
12212,3,4,cat,2
29889,7,6,dog,2
98900,2,1,gerbil,1
33221,1,8,squirrel,1
```

Comment: Do the csv files have headers?

Comment: @iRon the first one does, the second one can if it would make this possible. It doesn't need them but I can make it add them if necessary.

Comment: Can you add the headers (of the first file) to the question? Note that PowerShell object properties are usually directly related to the column headers.

Comment: I'll add placeholder headers. The real ones are identifiable so I'd rather keep them out a public question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.csv

```
id_number,location_code,category,animal,quantity
12212,3,4,cat,2
29889,7,6,dog,2
98900,
33221,1,8,squirrel,1
```

correction_001.csv

```
98900,2,1,gerbil,1
```

merge code used at the commandline, or in the .ps1 file of your choice

```
$myHeader = @('id_number','location_code','category','animal','quantity')

#Stage all the correction files: last correction in the most recent file wins
$ToFix = @{}
filter Plumbing_Import-Csv($Header){import-csv -LiteralPath $_ -Header $Header}
ls correction*.csv | sort -Property LastWriteTime | Plumbing_Import-Csv $myHeader | %{$ToFix[$_.id_number]=$_}

function myObjPipe($Header){
   begin{
      function TextTo-CsvField([String]$text){
         #text fields which contain comma, double quotes, or new-line are a special case for CSV fields and need to be accounted for
         if($text -match '"|,|\n'){return '"'+($text -replace '"','""')+'"'}
         return $text
      }
      function myObjTo-CsvRecord($obj){
         return ''+
            $obj.id_number               +','+
            $obj.location_code           +','+
            $obj.category                +','+
            (TextTo-CsvField $obj.animal)+','+
            $obj.quantity
      }
      $Header -join ','
   }

   process{
      if($ToFix.Contains($_.id_number)){
         $out = $ToFix[$_.id_number]
         $ToFix.Remove($_.id_number)
      }else{$out = $_}
      myObjTo-CsvRecord $out
   }

   end{
      #I assume you'd append any leftover fixes that weren't used
      foreach($out in $ToFix.Values){
         myObjTo-CsvRecord $out
      }
   }
}
import-csv main.csv | myObjPipe $myHeader | sc combined.csv -encoding ascii
```

You could also use `ConvertTo-Csv`, but my preference is to not have all the extra `"` cruft.

Edit 1: reduced code redundancy, accounted for `\n`, fixed appends, and used @OwlsSleeping suggestion about the -Header commandlet parameter

also works with these files:

correction_002.csv

```
98900,2,1,I Win,1
```

correction_new.csv

```
98901,2,1,godzilla,1
```

correction_too.csv

```
98902,2,1,gamera,1
98903,2,1,mothra,1
```

Edit 2: convert `gc | ConvertTo-Csv` over to `Import-Csv` to fix the front-end `\n` issues. Now also works with:

correction_003.csv

```
29889,7,6,"""bad""
monkey",2
```

Comment: I didn't expect the solution to be so involved (I was expecting some kind of one or two line sed equivalent like would be used on linux). Thanks for going to the trouble.

Comment: @Kefka if you knew for certain your data was well behaved then you could probably get away with `$b=gc correction.csv;$a=($b -replace '^(.*?),.*$','$1')+'.*';filter f{$_ -replace $a,$b};gc .\main.csv | f | sc .\combined.csv`

Comment: @Kefka, or `$b=gc correction.csv;$a=$b -replace '^(.*?),.*$','^$1,.*';gc main.csv | %{$_ -replace $a,$b} | sc combined.csv`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution assuming there's always exactly one match, and you don't care about output order. Change the output path to csv1 to overwrite.

I added headers manually in both input files, but you can specify them in Import-Csv instead if you'd rather avoid changing your files.

```
[array]$MissingLine = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Documents\csv2.csv"
[string]$MissingId = $MissingLine[0].id_number

[array]$BigCsv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Documents\csv1.csv" |
    Where-Object {$_.id_number -ne $MissingId}

($BigCsv + $MissingLine) | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Documents\Combined.csv"
```